# Rows-Element, where are these whitespaces coming from?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

First: My problem is that by inserting strings into several fields of a form from a row via DOM, the values occure with a lot of whitespaces, both at the beginning and the end.

What I want to do:
look up the values of the cells in the row I doubleclicked, and put these values in the fields of a form.

The HTML is equivalent to :

```
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend> Very Important </legend>
    <label for="input_representing_all_the_inputs">
    <input id="input_representing_all_the_inputs"></input>
  </fieldset>
</form>

<table id="issue_table" class="sortable", border="1" >
  <tr ondblclick="values_into_form(issue_table)">
    <td>
      a value
    </td>
    <td>
      another one
    <td>
  </tr>
  <tr ondblclick="values_into_form(issue_table)">
    <td>
      here's also another value
    </td>
    <td>
      aaand one more.
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table id="not_the_issue_table" class="sortable", border="1">
 [...] blabla looks similar [...]
</table>
```

Now I got a js function to look up values from the table and putting them into the form.

```
function values_into_form( id ) {
  //find index of row with given id
  for (i = 0; i<= document.getElementById("accl_content").rows.lenght; i++){
    if ( document.getElementById("issue_table").rows[i].id == id) {
        var idx = i;
        break;
    }
  }

  // now insert the values into the editor-form
  document.getElementById("input_representing_all_the_inputs" =
    document.getElementById("issue_table").rows[idx].cells[0];
  // repeat the above for each input_field with the specific cell_idx.
  }
}
```

So now, let's look at the first  of the first  of issue_table.
The value is "a value". However, the inputfield will contain something like "               a value            ".

Is there a specific misstake I made to produce this? 
I don't want a solution to get rid of the whitespaces, I want a real solution, want to say, I don't want them to occure at all.

I'm fresh to JS, coming from lua. So if I made some conceptional misstakes, I would be happy if you could tell me in a sidenote.

Comment: please add a fiddle so that we can see the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your html to this:

```
<table id="issue_table" class="sortable", border="1" >
  <tr ondblclick="values_into_form(issue_table)">
    <td>a value</td>
    <td>another one<td>
  </tr>
  <tr ondblclick="values_into_form(issue_table)">
    <td>here's also another value</td>
    <td>aaand one more.</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The spaces are because in your html there are spaces. You could of course alternatively strip beginning and ending white spaces using javascript. But if you do not want to do that, the above solution should work.

Comment: @Sempie No idea why this answer was originally down-voted, it's spot on. Here's an example showing why: https://jsfiddle.net/6sem6gc9/1/

Answer (score 1):

It is good practice to **separate** **HTML** and **JavaScript**.

**JavaScript**:

```
var myTable = document.getElementById("myTable");
var myInput = document.getElementById("myInput");
var td = myTable.getElementsByTagName("td");
for(var i = 0; i < td.length; i += 1) {
    td[i].addEventListener("dblclick", function() {
        myInput.value = this.innerHTML;
    });
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g94cyfom/2/)

Comment: What is the pro of not adding an eventListener to a row, but to each cell of it? Generically is good, I know, but this can also be archived per rows..

Comment: I've deleted the first sentences. Yes, you can achieve it by adding to every row an event listener. If you have 100 rows, you always must add the event listener. If you forget one... JavaScript apart from HTML, you can access every cell of the table only with the id of the table! You don't have to care about the HTML so much.